# Is it possible to pack a C struct into a NSKeyedArchiver in Cocoa?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, udp, nskeyedarchiver

I'm programming an iOS application which needs to communicate with a python app in a very effecient way thru UDP sockets.

In the middle I have a bonjour service which serves as a bridge for my iOS app and host python app to communicate.

I'm building my own protocol which is a simple C structure. The code that I had already as packing strings into NSKeyedArchiver entities which by their turn would be packed in NSData and sent. In the other side there is a NSKeyedUnarchiver.

The problem is that it can't understand the C struct i'm sending. Is there a way of putting a C structure inside a NSKeyedArchiver? How should I modify my middle service to remove this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.

Read the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html), everything is explained here with samples, including this case, especially the part [Encoding and decoding C Data Types](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingctypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001294-BBCBDHBI) :)

Answer (score -1):

Rather than use NSData - and if the struct contains simple data items, rather than objects pointers you can use NSValue

```
NSValue valueFromStruct = [[NSValue value:&aStruct withObjCType:@encode(YourStructType)] retain];
```

As NSValue conforms to the NSCoding protocol you can use the methods that you want to use.

Comment: -[NSKeyedArchiver encodeValueOfObjCType:at:]: this archiver cannot encode structs'

Comment: I had this exception when creating the NSValue